# Link parent-child by value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `Account` with `Account_id` as a Unique PK, in this structure

```
Value                Name                                        Account_id
------              -------                                      ----------
1                    Assets                                          100
11                   Fixed Assets                                    101
111                  Furniture and office equipment                  102
1111                 Chairs                                          105
1112                 Computers                                       104
1113                 Air Conditioners                                103
12                   Under-Development Projects                      108
121                  Lands                                           109
122                  Roads and Buildings                             110
1221                 Buildings                                       111
2                    Revenues                                        107
21                   Hotel                                           120
211                  Room                                            122
212                  Sweet                                           123
22                   House                                           125
3                    Liabilities                                     113

and so on...
```

Accounts with value **11** and **12**(**Fixed Assets** and **Under-Development Projects**) are sub-accounts for value **1**(**Assets**). also account **111** is sub-account for **11**, and account **1111** and **1112** and **1113** are sub-account for **111**. to understand better, we can say level1, level2, level3, and level4. like this

```
level1                level2                 level3             level4
   1                    11                    111                1111
                                                                 1112
                                                                 1113
                        12                    121
                                              122                1221
   2                    21                    211
                                              212
                        22
```

Hope you'll got the idea.
Now, I have another table `Payment` to handle payments, in this structure

```
Account_id                 Debit               Credit
------------              -------             --------
    105                   500000                 0
    103                   350000                 0
    110                     0                 300000
    105                     0                 300000
    111                   250000                 0
    105                   100000                 0
    111                     0                 400000
    122                   400000                 0
    123                     0                 250000
```

Note: Payments are only on level3 and level4 accounts
the resulting table should be like this

```
Value             Name                                          Amount
------            -----                                        ---------
1                 Assets                                        200,000
11                Fixed Assets                                  650,000
111               Furniture and office equipment                650,000
1111              Chairs                                        300,000
1112              Computers                                        0
1113              Air Conditioners                              350,000
12                Under-Development Projects                   -450,000
121               Lands                                            0
122               Roads and Buildings                          -450,000 
1221              Buildings                                    -150,000
2                 Revenue                                       150,000
21                Hotel                                         150,000
211               Room                                          400,000
212               Sweet                                        -150,000

and so on...
```

The Amount column is the result of `Debit-Credit`. Here's a brief
every account will show the full amount of all its sub-accounts. e.g. Furniture and office equipment(value 111), will be:
`amount of 111 + amount of 1111 + amount of 1112 + amount of 1113`

 which is 500000+350000-300000+100000=650000

Answer (score 0):

Left join payment to account, sum amounts. Use these rows to create recursive CTE. Starting points are children, with ids which are not substrings of others. Then attach parents recursively:

```
with t(value, name, account_id, amount) as (
    select value, name, account_id, sum(debit - credit) 
      from account a 
    natural left join payment p 
    group by account_id, value, name),
  c(value, name, account_id, amount) as (
    select value, name, account_id, amount 
      from t 
      where not exists (select 1 from account where value like t.value||'_' )
    union all
    select t.value, t.name, t.account_id, nvl(c.amount, 0) + nvl(t.amount, 0)
      from t join c on t.value = substr(c.value, 1, length(c.value) - 1))
select value, name, account_id, sum(amount) amount 
  from c 
  group by value, name, account_id
  order by to_char(value)
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ec35edf5d217952720bd4ca79ad9853)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query correlated on matching the leading sub-string of the `account.value` column:

```sql
SELECT a.*,
       COALESCE(
         ( SELECT SUM( debit - credit )
           FROM   payment p
                  INNER JOIN account ac
                  ON ( p.account_id = ac.account_id )
           WHERE  ac.value LIKE a.value || '%'
         ),
         0
       ) AS amount
FROM   account a
```

which outputs:

> ```
> VALUE | NAME                           | ACCOUNT_ID |  AMOUNT
> :---- | :----------------------------- | ---------: | ------:
> 1     | Assets                         |        100 |  200000
> 11    | Fixed Assets                   |        101 |  650000
> 111   | Furniture and office equipment |        102 |  650000
> 1111  | Chairs                         |        105 |  300000
> 1112  | Computers                      |        104 |       0
> 1113  | Air Conditioners               |        103 |  350000
> 12    | Under-Development Projects     |        108 | -450000
> 121   | Lands                          |        109 |       0
> 122   | Roads and Buildings            |        110 | -450000
> 1221  | Buildings                      |        111 | -150000
> 2     | Revenues                       |        107 |  150000
> 21    | Hotel                          |        120 |  150000
> 211   | Room                           |        122 |  400000
> 212   | Sweet                          |        123 | -250000
> 22    | House                          |        125 |       0
> 3     | Liabilities                    |        113 |       0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ff73889e3642f7f957bba047b412433)*